# how to use a proxy above an aws lambda invocation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to invoke an aws lambda function through java code using the aws lamdba sdk while specifying a proxy above the client. How can I achieve such scenario? I did not manage to locate any documentation on aws docs.

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I have something like this, and i want to specify a proxy here. Any idea?

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    lambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()
            // specify a proxy here maybe or a custom httpclient ?
            .region(Region.EU_SOUTH_1)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235387/how-to-set-proxy-on-aws-java-sdk-v2-apache-client

Comment: This is documented in the *AWS SDK Jave V2 Developer Guide*. This topic contains information on how to configure the Apache-based HTTP client. See this topic: [Configure the Apache-based HTTP client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration-apache.html#http-configuration-apache-proxy-conf-ex)

Comment: What docs are you referring to when you state this is not documented. Are you looking in a Service Guide or the Java V2 Dev Guide. I posted a link in the DEV Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily build your own custom http client for the AWS SDK:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  final SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder()
            .proxyConfiguration(ProxyConfiguration.builder()
            .useSystemPropertyValues(true)
            .build())
       .build();

  lambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder().httpClient(httpClient).build();
}
```

- [HTTP clients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration.html)
- [ProxyConfiguration](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/apache/ProxyConfiguration.html)
- [SdkHttpClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/SdkHttpClient.html)